# Language detections with apache Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika, language-detection

I am currently trying to get along with Apache Tika and set up a language detection that checks all keyValues of my various properties files for the correct language of the respective file. Unfortunately the detection is not really good..All keys are not recognized with the correct language and I don't know how I can do it better. An api solution is out of the question, because I have the order to find a free way and most free connections only allow 1000 calls per day (in german alone I have more than 14000 keys).

If you know how I can make the current code better or maybe have another solution, please let me know!

Thanks a lot,
Pascal

Thats my Current code:

```
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.tika.language.LanguageIdentifier;

public class detect {

  @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final MyPropAllKeys mPAK = new MyPropAllKeys("messages_forCheck.properties");
    final Set<Object> keys = mPAK.getAllKeys();

    for (final Object key : keys) {
      final String keyString = key.toString();
      final String keyValueString = mPAK.getPropertyValue(keyString);

      detect(keyValueString, key);

    }

  }

  public static void detect(String keyValueString, Object key) {
    final LanguageIdentifier languageIdentifier = new LanguageIdentifier(keyValueString);

    final String language = languageIdentifier.getLanguage();
    if (!language.equals("de")) {
      System.out.println(language + " " + key + ": " + keyValueString);

    }
  }

}
```

For Example thats some of the Results:

```
pt de.segal.baoss.platform.entity.BackgroundTaskType.MASS_INVOICE_DOCUMENT_CREATION: Rechnungsdokumente erzeugen

sk de.segal.baoss.purchase.supplier.creditorNumber: Kreditorennummer

no de.segal.baoss.module.crm.revenueLastYear: Umsatz vergangenes Jahr

no de.segal.baoss.module.op.customerReturn.action.createCreditEntry: Gutschrift erstellen
```

All are definitely German

Comment: The Tika language detection is stats-based, and works better on longer blocks of text, any chance you could feed more text in?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The key/values are already pre-defined :/ Is there perhaps another library that is more suitable for me?

Comment: If it is just a few words each time, maybe just grab spell checking dictionaries for a bunch of languages, and check in those?